# Google StreetView isn't supported by your browser in Microsoft Access Web Browser control

Tags: browser, ms-access

I am trying to display a Google StreetView in a Web Browser control on a Microsoft Access form.  I get an error that StreetView isn't supported.

How can I overcome this problem?  What "browser" is the Web Browser control using?  Here is a pic of the error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, msaccess.exe uses an old version of MSIE in the StreetViewBrowser.Object.

In order to force msaccess.exe to use a newer version of MSIE in the StreetViewBrowser.Object, you can use this simple registry hack:

https://www.devhut.net/2013/10/18/webbrowser-activex-control-google-maps-invalid-character-scripting-error/

In my case I followed the example and entered a DWord value of 9999 to Force IE9 Emulation.  Everything works fine now!